# Vaadin: Tabs are displayed in a really bizarre way - is this intended?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am really puzzled about Vaadin's Tabs/Tab-component:

I have created a page with a couple of tabs essentially like this:

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
Tab tab1 = new Tab("Label 1");
tab1.add(<some components (labels and entry fields) here>);
tabs.add(tab1);

Tab tab2 = new Tab("Label 2");
tab2.add(<some components (labels and entry fields) here>);
tabs.add(tab2);

Tab tab3 = new Tab("Label 3");
tab3.add(<some components (labels and entry fields) here>);
tabs.add(tab3);

mainPage.add(tabs)
```

What I would have expected to get rendered is something similar to this (modulo some styling of course):

```
 ___________  ___________  ___________
/  Label 1  \/ *Label 2* \/  Label 3  \
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Content of Tab 2 visible                           |
|                                                    |
| (the other tabs' contents is hidden until their    |
|  corresponding tab is selected )                   |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I.e. I have a list of titles marking individual tabs or "pages", only ONE of which has its content displayed underneath. Here, e.g. assume that tab 2 is currently selected, hence in the area below I can see its contents, while the contents of tab 1 and tab 3 are currently hidden.

Now, the Vaadin Tabs are displayed like this:

```
            [content 1]                 [content 2]             [content 3]  
   Label 1  [content 1]      *Label 2*  [content 2]    Label 3  [content 3]
            [content 1]                 [content 2]             [content 3]
            [content 1]                 [content 2]             [content 3]
                                     -----
```

I.e. each tab's contents is shown next to the corresponding label and ALL contents are visible at the same time. The line indicates the currently selected tab.

This is the most bizarre implementation of the Tab concept and looks totally broken to me! Is this really intended to display like this? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Tabs` component is only for displaying the tabs themselves, it doesn't control the content like `TabSheet` did in Vaadin 8 and earlier. A `TabSheet` component is on the backlog as far as I know.

In the meantime, you can construct your own similar to this (from https://cookbook.vaadin.com/tabsheet)

```java
package com.vaadin.recipes.recipe.tabsheet;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Span;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.recipes.recipe.Metadata;
import com.vaadin.recipes.recipe.Recipe;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Route("tabsheet")
@Metadata(
    howdoI = "create a TabSheet component",
    description = "Learn how to change content based on the selected tab in a Vaadin Java app."
)
public class TabSheetView extends Div {
    /**
     * Contents of the TabSheet.
     */
    private final Map<Tab, Component> contents = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public TabSheetView() {
        this.buildContentAndTabs();

        // tabs component
        final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();

        // display area
        final Div display = new Div();
        display.setSizeFull();

        // show components on the screen
        this.add(tabs, display);

        // update display area whenever tab selection changes
        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(
            event -> {
                // remove old contents, if there was a previously selected tab
                if (event.getPreviousTab() != null) display.remove(this.contents.get(event.getPreviousTab()));
                // add new contents, if there is a currently selected tab
                if (event.getSelectedTab() != null) display.add(this.contents.get(event.getSelectedTab()));
            }
        );

        // add tabs to the component
        tabs.add(this.contents.keySet().toArray(new Tab[0]));
    }

    /**
     * Builds contents to be displayed and the corresponding tabs. Uses the first
     * articles from <a href=
     * "https://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/index.html">the
     * Universal Declaration of Human Rights</a>.
     */
    private void buildContentAndTabs() {
        final String[] data = new String[] {
            "Article 1.",
            "All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood.",
            "Article 2.",
            "Everyone is entitled to all the rights and freedoms set forth in this Declaration, without distinction of any kind, such as race, colour, sex, language, religion, political or other opinion, national or social origin, property, birth or other status. Furthermore, no distinction shall be made on the basis of the political, jurisdictional or international status of the country or territory to which a person belongs, whether it be independent, trust, non-self-governing or under any other limitation of sovereignty.",
            "Article 3.",
            "Everyone has the right to life, liberty and security of person.",
            "Article 4.",
            "No one shall be held in slavery or servitude; slavery and the slave trade shall be prohibited in all their forms.",
            "Article 5.",
            "No one shall be subjected to torture or to cruel, inhuman or degrading treatment or punishment.",
            "Article 6.",
            "Everyone has the right to recognition everywhere as a person before the law.",
        };
        // create tabs and matching contents
        for (int zmp1 = 0; zmp1 < data.length; zmp1 += 2) this.contents.put(
                new Tab(data[zmp1]),
                new Span(data[zmp1 + 1])
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah - I see. That `Tabs` and `Tab` only control the headers (and are thus IMHO only a fragment of the implementation that one would expect) didn't become apparent at all to me from the description. Might be worthwhile to make that more specific in the documentation! Thanks for clarifying and providing that work-around skeleton! Highly appreciated!