# Vaadin: Can't move a node from one state tree to another exception

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I am getting this exception in my Vaadin app when I try to hide a tab and set the selected tab to the correct one.

I'm using Spring and everything is marked as @UIScope in the config.

I have been looking at this for days and am struggling to work out the issue. What I do know is removing @PreserveOnRefresh fixes it but I need this as well....

I'm using Vaadin 22.0.28

My code looks like this:

```
@PageTitle("Instruments")
@Route(value = "instrument", layout = MainView.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = MainView.class)
@CssImport("./views/instrument/instrument-tabs-view.css")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class InstrumentTabsView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final Map<Tab, Component> tabsComponentCache = new HashMap<>();
    private final Tab cmdTab = new Tab(getTranslation(T_CMD));
    private final Tab crTab = new Tab(getTranslation(T_CR));
    private final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
    private Component grid;
    private final Supplier<Universe> universeSupplier;


    public InstrumentTabsView(@Autowired CmdInstrumentsGridView cmdInstrumentsGridView,
                              @Autowired CrInstrumentsGridView crInstrumentsGridView,
                              @Autowired Supplier<Universe> universeSupplier) {
        this.universeSupplier = universeSupplier;
        setSizeFull();

        tabsComponentCache.put(cmdTab, cmdInstrumentsGridView);
        tabsComponentCache.put(crTab, crInstrumentsGridView);


        grid = cmdInstrumentsGridView;
        tabs.add(cmdTab, crTab);
        setAppropriateTabs();
        tabs.addClassName("assetClassTabs");
        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            Component newGrid = tabsComponentCache.get(event.getSelectedTab());
            replace(grid, newGrid); // <- error thrown here
            grid = newGrid;
        });

        add(tabs, grid);

        addAttachListener(e -> {
            ((BaseGridView) grid).refreshGrid();
            setAppropriateTabs();
        });

    }

    private void setAppropriateTabs() {
        Universe universe = universeSupplier.get();
        if (universe != null && UniverseType.VAR.equals(universe.getType())) {
            cmdTab.setVisible(false);
            setSelectedTab(AssetClass.CR);
        }
        else {
            cmdTab.setVisible(true);
            setSelectedTab(AssetClass.CMD);
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedTab(AssetClass assetClass) {
        Tab selectedTab;
        switch (assetClass) {
            case CMD:
                selectedTab = cmdTab;
                break;
            case CR:
                selectedTab = crTab;
                break;
            default:
                selectedTab = null;
                break;
        }
        tabs.setSelectedTab(selectedTab);
    }
}
```

The page is refreshed when a drop down in the MainView changes which calls

```
getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.getPage().reload());
```

I have tried to see where in the Vaadin code the issue is and it seems to be the StateNode.class in this method where isOwnerAttached resolves as true.

```
private void doSetTree(StateTree tree) {
        if (tree != this.getOwner()) {
            if (this.getOwner() instanceof StateTree) {
                boolean isOwnerAttached = ((StateTree)this.getOwner()).getRootNode().isAttached();
                boolean isNotReplaced = ComponentUtil.getData(((StateTree)this.getOwner()).getUI(), ReplacedViaPreserveOnRefresh.class) == null;
                if (isOwnerAttached || isNotReplaced) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Can't move a node from one state tree to 
another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree");
                }

                this.id = -1;
            }

            this.owner = tree;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you tested without `@PreserveOnRefresh`, have you tried with multiple concurrent browser sessions? Also in the past this problem showed up with POR although it shouldn't (bug) - are you on the most recent versions?

Comment: Running 22.0.28. I don't see any issues with concurrent browsers, it is behaving as I would expect.

Comment: If it's still not working with 23 or 24, I'd create an MRE and report a bug.

Comment: What's super weird is that I can change from the tab being hidden to being shown to being hidden again but the next change to show it again throws the error

Comment: There is something wrong in your cached components bookkeeping. You are caching references to components that are possibly attached, and when you pick it from cache and try to add it to other layout, this error is thrown as a component can be attached to exactly one parent at the time.

Comment: @WillyM that "what's super weird"-comment without context is just confusing. Does that mean, that POR is _not_ relevant? Please add new insights to the question instead of comments.

Comment: @cfrick - this is with POR as that is required

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the problem is rooted in your `private final Map<Tab, Component> tabsComponentCache = new HashMap<>();`. When you're using `@PreserveOnRefresh`, the component with the annotation is switched over to the new UI and new state tree when you refresh. I presume the components in the Map are still in the old state tree (maybe they're not direct children of the annotated component?), and thus you're getting the exception. You should probably clear the Map when the root view component is detached. I'd also evaluate the use of the `tabsComponentCache`, it feels like an anti-pattern (but I can't confirm that with the given information).

Comment: You are probably right but I'm not sure how to use tabs in another way. I have seen this pattern in a number of different posts, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813267/vaadin-tabs-are-displayed-in-a-really-bizarre-way-is-this-intended

Comment: Clearing the map on detach should be a good starting point.